# overriding css_xhtml in struts2

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

This is my jsp code here i am using struts2 my question is to how to override the struts2 with the css_xhtml, i am very new to the struts2 plz help me out thk u

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<s:form action="register" method="post" theme="css_xhtml">
<s:textfield key="bean.uname"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield key="bean.email"></s:textfield>
<s:textfield key="bean.mobile"></s:textfield>
<s:password key="bean.pwd"></s:password>
<s:password key="bean.rpwd"></s:password>
<s:submit value="submit" align="center"></s:submit>
<s:actionerror/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Create CSS for it.

Comment: how to create css to align the form by overriding css_xhtml theme thnk u

Comment: Do you want to give "css_xhtml" to form and different theme to particular element of form OR want to change theme of whole form?

Comment: actually i am very new to it i don't know how to do it plz assist me

Comment: have you tried theme="simple"?

Comment: i have given css_xhtml to form tag, now where can i create my css file and link to it ,,

Comment: no i'm not trying theme simple,i'm using css_xhtml

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/css/.

Comment: i didn't get the answer from w3schools.com can any one plz assist me in it

Comment: can anyone plz assist me

Comment: its urgent can anyone plz assist me

Comment: Assist with what exactly? How to write CSS? How to include CSS?

Comment: i know how to include css and write without using struts2 but i don't understand with struts2 thnk u

Comment: can u see above code am using css_xhtml theme whts the use of it...

Comment: hi can anyone plz assist me for above question

Comment: Why you are using "css_xhtml" and not "simple"?

Comment: can u plz tell me whts the diff between simple and css_xhtml

Comment: how to design ui for the above code

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_themes_templates.htm
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/ - These links will help you about the templates & themes present in struts2 and how to customize or create new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see people tried a lot to explain you, but you simply don't get. Anyways, let me also try once :

1. Use "simple" theme - this way you can write most of your customization
2. I've written a sample form with some CSS layouting to help you out.

> ```
> <s:form action="register" method="post" theme="simple">
> <table>
> <tr>
> <td><label>Username</label></td>
> <td><s:textfield key="bean.uname" cssClass="username"></s:textfield></td>
> </tr><tr>
> <td><label>Email</label></td>
> <td>
> <s:textfield key="bean.email" cssClass="email"></s:textfield>
> </td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
> <td colspan="2">
> <s:submit/>
> </td>
> </tr>
> </table>
> </s:form>
> ```

```
<style>
.username{
   border:1px solid;
}
.email{
   padding:10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: k i agree with it, but my question is to whts the use of css_xhtml theme and how to use in the jsp and create css for that thnk u

Comment: please see the links I provided in the question. In order to modify the css_xhtml theme, you have to change the core struts2 files. I suggest creating a new theme instead.

Comment: can u plz update me one sample example by using css_xhtml thnk u

Comment: well I won't ever do that! I'll just use "simple" and write my own custom css, instead of taking the pain to modify the css_xhtml theme. I've written 100+ struts2 projects as of now and never felt such a need.

Comment: glad you agreed that for most customization `simple` is the best to use, although `css_xhtml` & `xhtml` are quite handy for a simple layout.

Answer (score 1):

try <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

instead of <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

Comment: if i use that tag am getting warning messages thnk u plz help me

Comment: my question is to how to write the css for it

Comment: you can write css using class. In jsp add classes <s:password key="bean.pwd" class="input-field"></s:password> ( or use the format how tag lib using for class ) and give style for that class.

Comment: can u plz tell me whts the use of css_xhtml theme in form tag

Comment: Hi, I have no more idea about jsp. But I can help you in css. css_xhtml is a theming in strut 2. http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/struts-2-themes.html . you can refer this page for more details.

Comment: i do have to create class for all tgs like  <s:password key="bean.pwd" class="input-field"> in jsp then whts the use of css_xhtml